# What are the unique field variations in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am writing a script that checks for unique constraint conflicts before inserting data into a table.

Disregarding the Primary key, are there more variations than these?

1. There exists **only one unique field** in the table
2. There exists **multiple unique fields** in the table
3. There exists **a unique field which is a composite** (unique combination of fields)
4. A combination of (1 or 2) with 3

Does variation number 2 make any sense? Is it used in practice or would it be considered bad design?

Comment: Of course (2) makes sense.  It happens all the time.  Consider a database of customers . . . the customer id might be unique, the start date could be unique (if the database is not that big), the address could be unique, the phone number could be unique, . . .  I'm not saying all these should be declared unique, but they might be unique in practice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So to check would you do a SELECT ... WHERE Unique_field_1 IN (...) **OR** Unique_field_2 IN (...)

Comment: Why would you need to check their uniqueness when you don't know whether they are *required* to be unique?

Comment: @joop am trying to make a generic script which would check for any variant of unique fields in a table. So in case any of these variants exist, the code wont break

Comment: Cardinality: `count distinct a,b,c,... == count(*)` is the condition you are after. It is still nonsensical: your table is actually a *sample* from a larger universe; for instance:  `date_of_birth` *could* be unique, until new data arrives.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement all other comments, yes, all those variations are possible and recommended, according to your **business model**. The business model is what drives all the constraints. Take the example below:

```
create table employee (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  ssn varchar(10) not null,
  branch_id int not null,
  in_branch_serial int not null,
  constraint uq_name unique (name),
  constraint uq_ssn unique (ssn),
  constraint uq_employee_number unique (branch_id, in_branch_serial)
);
```

This table has:

- The `id` is unique, since it's the primary key.
- The `name` is also unique, we decided we wanted it this way.
- The `ssn` is also unique, per our business model.
- The `branch_id` + `in_branch_serial` combination is unique. Employees on the same branch will have the same `branch_id`, but the combination of both columns will be unique.

Comment: You are right. The example is cleaner with a non-nullable column.

Answer (score 2):

The word that is missing from your question is KEY. A table can have zero, one or more keys. In a relational database a table must have at least one key but SQL DBMSs do permit tables without keys.

Any key may consist of zero, one or more attributes. Keys can sometimes overlap - meaning attribute(s) in one key are also attributes in another, although this is relatively unusual.

A key may also have zero attributes. This is the case for singleton tables - tables that are constrained to have (at most) one row. The DUAL system table in Oracle is a well-known example. SQL unfortunately doesn't support an "empty" key syntax but there are some workarounds used to achieve the same effect.

Usually data gets checked against keys that are already known. Deriving keys from data is not normally a useful exercise unless your data is truly never changing. If a table has just 10 (non-nullable) attributes then it may have a maximum of 252 keys out of 1024 possible superkeys, so checking all of the possibilities is a fairly hard problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about zero-column keys?

Comment: @TheImpaler http://web.onetel.com/~hughdarwen/M359/FD-demystification.html#emptyset

Comment: Excellent description. DUAL follows this idea as well as any singleton table. Thanks.